# Recording Stereo With U-Phoria UM2

Tags: recording, keyboard, digital-piano, mono, stereo

I record my Clavinova CLP-360 with a Behringer UM2 interface. However, I can only record in mono using only one of the inputs on the interface. Would I be able to record in stereo if I connected separate L/R inputs into the two on the interface? My only worry is that since (on the interface) one, I think, is specially made for low-level inputs. Would that affect it, other than volume?

Also, on a less important note, IF all goes well and I record in stereo, could I **hear** stereo through the live monitor output on the interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You COULD do it if it’s the only option. Use a DI box for the mic/Line input and then adjust the input gains to preference.

You will not be able to hear stereo from the direct monitor setting.

Comment: Ok. Could you clarify the function of the DI Box? I use the two interface inputs interchangeably (signal coming from the 1/4" headphone jack output) with no problems. I of course always have the mic +48v switched off (its an option on the back of the interface). Seems to work fine all the time.

Comment: @Galaxy the DI box is for matching the impedance of the XLR input. It may work without it but not as well. http://whirlwindusa.com/support/tech-articles/direct-box-can-be-di-spensible/